# Mplayer music library like banshee or wmp

Tags: music, mplayer, hd-video

Hi I have been looking around for a plug in to make mplayer act as a music library but to no avail.

Dose any one know of one ?

My aim is to find one media player that can do music and films (must support x264 banshee dose not) a bit like windows media player but on Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Banshee should support x264 if you have the plug-ins installed for it, which I believe are not installed by default. However, if you install the `gstreamer0.10-plugins-ugly` or `gstreamer0.10-ffmpeg` packages, then any x264 videos should also play in Banshee.

Comment: That worked thakx

Comment: Unfortunately play back is very choppy anyone know a fix ?

Comment: A driver update fixed (nvidia) fixed choppy playback